Divergent/Unbounded random walks techniques
I want to prove the following biased random walk will be diverge. Suppose I have a random walk $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$, but $X_1,...,X_n$ are dependent variables. $X_1 \sim$ Bernoulli($\sigma(\theta_1)$), where $\theta_1= 0$. After sampling, I update $\theta_2 = \theta_1 + 2(\sigma(\theta_1) - X_1)$, where $\sigma$ is a sigmoid function and $X_2\sim$Bernoulli($\theta_2)$. Generally, $\theta_n = \theta_{n-1}+2(\sigma(\theta_{n-1})-X_{n-1})$ and $X_n \sim \sigma(\theta_n)$. From experiment, I observed that the random walk diverge, but very slowly, and I try to prove that it is in fact divergent.
I have looked into this blog, which shows how to prove a asymetrical random walk will diverge using law of large numbers. However, I don't think it is transferable to this case since I have a non-i.i.d setting.
What are typical approaches to prove unbounded/divergent non-i.i.d random walk? Any resources/exercises are very appriciated!

I assume you want your $X_i$ to be $\pm 1$; not 0,1?

Actually, $X_i$ is ${0,1}$ since it is a Bernoulli random variable.

So you mean $2(X_1-1)+\dots+2(X_n-1)$ diverges.

I agree that this is not a typical/simple random walk in the sense $X_i = {-1,1}$. My main point is I am unfamilar with the proof techniques/tools. If you may know, can you please introduce me to those tools!

I think the standard tool is to use Law of Large Number, but I believe it assume you have an i.i.d random variables $X_i$, which is not applicable in this case.

Sorry, I don't think I follow your arguments. Can you explain more details?

$\theta_n$ is a Markov Chain and studying its Markov Kernel might help. Meanwhile, I tried to develop some intuition but failed. Here is what I meant. If we take the logistic function $\sigma(\theta) = \frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta}$ then
$$\theta_{n+1}= \begin{cases}\theta_n+2\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta}&\text{with probability }\frac{1}{1+e^\theta}\
\theta_n-2\frac{1}{1+e^\theta}&\text{with probability }\frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta}
\end{cases}$$
Applying eight times the transition to $\theta_n=3$ yields
$\theta_{n+8}\approx 18.9$ with probability $\approx 4\times10^{-35}, \dots$

$\theta_{n+8}\approx 4.0$ with probability $\approx 0.06$ or $ \theta_{n+8}\approx 3.8$ with probability $\approx 0.07$ or $ \theta_{n+8}\approx 1.8$ with probability $\approx 0.55$. Therefore $\theta_n = 3$ has more chance to go down around $1.8$ than to go above $3.8$. It is even better for starting numbers $\theta_n$ higher than $3$, applying the transition until you can be sure $\theta_{n+k}$ is about $\theta_{n}-1$ or about greater than $\theta_{n}+1$. There is always more chance for $\theta_{n}-1$ (its probability tends to be about $0.607$). Unfortunately, that argument doesn't help.
